# Same action but different default params

Tags: c#, api, routes

I have an action which I would like to have the same functionality for disabling and enabling TFA as all I need to do is change the `bool` flag for the setup tfa method like so:

```
[HttpPost("enable-tfa")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Enable()
{
   var providers = await _identityManager.SetTwoFactorEnabled(true);

   if (!providers.Any())
       return Forbid();

   return Ok();
}
```

I want to be able to use this method for both routes:

```
[HttpPost("enable-tfa")]
```

and

```
[HttpPost("disbale-tfa")]
```

But for each of them I would like to pass either `true` or `false` to the `SetTwoFactorEnabled()` method. rather than having 2 separate actions that basically do the same thing. I also don't want to rely on the client sending `true` or `false`

Comment: For this small example I don't see any problem with having two different actions. And they don't do the same thing, the one enables MFA and the other disables it. If more work needs being done you can create a private method which takes a bool and do the work there.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `bool` parameter to the actions method and write your logic based on its value i.e. `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this. Here is one of them. We are going to have a query parameter named `enable`

```
[HttpPost("enable-tfa")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EnableTFA([FromQuery] bool enable)
{
   var providers = await _identityManager.SetTwoFactorEnabled(enable);

   if (!providers.Any())
       return Forbid();

   return Ok();
}
```

Then you can call it as: `http://example.com/api/enable-tfa?enable=true`